# Table with name and nationality for sprinters

Tags: r

I have a dataset with men's 100m dash world record holders' names, their records, their nationality, and the date they ran it. This is the image of the data:

[image: sample data]

I read it into R, and would like to create a table that goes like:

```
Usain Bolt      Jamaica
Asafa Powell    Jamaica
Carl Lewis      USA 
....
```

The code

```
table(100men$name,100men$nationality)
```

doesn't get me what I want (it makes this table: [table formed by the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3oYF.png)). How do you get it with code?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data has the column names as indicated in your data image, you can use dplyr to manipulate it as you'd like. For example, if you wanted to see Athlete and Nation,

```
library("dplyr")
data %>%
  group_by(Athlete, Nation) %>%
  distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand your question, it sounds like your original table contains all the information you need. So, just delete the unnecessary columns. For example:

```
# Make example dataset. 
X = data.frame("name" = c("Usain Bolt", "Asafa Powell", "Carl Lewis"),
               "nationality" = c("Jamaica", "Jamaica", "USA"),
               "time" = c(9.59, 10.2, 9.3))

# Subset data to just include name and nationality
X2 = X[, which(colnames(X) %in% c("name", "nationality"))]
X2 #showing output
```

If you're worried about duplicates (e.g., perhaps Usain Bolt has two rows in the original data), you can use `X2 = X2[!duplicated(X2), ]` to retain only unique records.

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is in columns 1 and 2, you can just go

```
unique(data[,1:2])
```

where `data` is the name of your dataframe.